# How to start socket.io connection after authenticating in AngularJS?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sockets, authentication

I have an AngularJS with a login form that calls to some URL endpoints to authenticate users. These endpoints return values and I create a session cookie, and allow the users access to the inner parts of the application.

After authenticating, I need to establish a socket.io connection, however in AngularJS whenever I switch states in the application (i.e. move to the dashboard after logging in), the socket.io connection event to my server never occurs. The only way I can work around this is to refresh the page, where the socket.io module connects and all the data starts flowing.

I'm using angular-socket-io and I think its possible to invoke my socket factory after authenticating, but it seems to always invoke immediately on the login form.

Any ideas?

**What's happening currently:**

1) Socket connection attempted with no auth_token, fails

2) User logs in

3) Browser refresh

4) Socket connection attempted with auth_token, accepted

**Goal:**

1) User logs in

2) State change to dashboard

3) Socket connection created using auth_token, accepted

Comment: I worked around this by using a redirect after logging in to reload the page.

Comment: Thats the current solution that I use, however it's not ideal obviously. Seems kind of hacky.